# How to find specific text & print the next 2 words after it

Tags: python, tesseract

My code is below.

I currently have an if statement that finds a specific word, in this case 'INGREDIENTS'.

Next,
Instead of `print("true")` I need to print next 2 words/strings from 'INGREDIENTS'. This word/string appears once in the image ('INGREDIENTS').

As an example, I run the .py file and this is my output if I include this in my script: `print(text)`

```
Ground Almonds

INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds(100%).

1kg
```

I just need to re-code this section:

```
if 'INGREDIENTS' in text:
 print("True")
else:
 print("False")
```

so the output is like this:

```
INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds
```

Becasue next two words/strings are `Ground` and `Almonds`

**Python Code**

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\gzi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tesseract.exe'

img=Image.open('C:/Users/gzi/Desktop/work/lux.jpg')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang = 'eng')


if 'INGREDIENTS' in text:
 print("True")
else:
 print("False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the percentage and want to avoid `regex`:

```
string = 'INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds(100%).'

tokens = string.split()
for n,i in enumerate(tokens):
    if 'INGREDIENTS' in i:
        print(' '.join(tokens[n:n+3]))
```

Output:

```
INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds(100%).
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I like the idea of `[n:n+3]` I am able to choose the index easily

Comment: I'm glad I helped !

Comment: Nice code! Just make sure if you want to make it more generic it is better to locate the ending index too

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming we have the following text extracted, using `pytesseract`:

```py
text = '''Ground Almonds
INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds(100%).
1kg'''
```

We can achieve the desired result by:

```py
first_index = text.find('INGREDIENTS')
second_index = text.find('(')
my_string = f'{text[first_index:second_index]}'
print(my_string)
```

And the output being:

```py
INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds
```

So in the code snippet we use `find` method to locate the `INGREDIENTS` word and the `(` symbol (assuming it will always come after the main ingredient, specifying the percentage of it).

We then use `string` slicing with the above indexes and print the result, formatting it to the desired output with `f-string`.

Comment: Class! I understand the first two lines of your code. But not the 3rd, if you have spare time, please can you explain it?

Comment: This won't work if there's not a percentage attached to your ingredient, though. Is it important to not show the percentage?

Comment: Let's say I wanted only the first word from `INGREDIENTS` which will be `Ground`. How would this impact the current code?

Comment: @98Ed, please see my edited answer, I explained more on the code :)

Comment: @JuanC, you are right Juan, that is why I assumed there is a percentage attached

Answer (score 1):

Find with regex all match:

```
import re

txt = "INGREDIENTS: Ground Almonds(\"100\");"
x = re.findall("INGREDIENTS:\s(\w+)\s(\w+)", txt)
print(x)

# [('Ground', 'Almonds')]
```

Comment: Hi, i like this idea. I have changed the code slightly to `txt = text`. This is actually really good and can work from this.